# Make last child visible when hover

Tags: css, hover, html-lists

I'm making my nav pure css but I'm trying to make child li visible when hovering parent, i tried `{
    opacity: 1; visibility: visible;}` but It won't work. help :(

***this is my code:***

http://jsfiddle.net/x5SbW/

Comment: Please include the [relevant parts of the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain in specific terms what you're trying to accomplish and how your results differ from the desired results. Please read this advice on asking good questions: [ask] and [Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/1tBMnR). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your structure of HTML was wrong -

you were using -

```
     <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
     <ul class="resub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">resub</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">resub</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">resub</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
```

but if should have been -

```
<li><a href="#">sub1</a>
     <ul class="resub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">resub</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">resub</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">resub</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

in short, your `<ul>` were outside `<li>`

http://jsfiddle.net/x5SbW/1/